# Frog jumping algorithm

Tags: ruby, programming-challenge

I took a test on Codility for coding the minimum number of frog jumps to reach from position x to position y:

> A small frog wants to get to the other side of the road. The frog is
>   currently located at position X and wants to get to a position greater
>   than or equal to Y. The small frog always jumps a fixed distance, D.
>   Count the minimal number of jumps that the small frog must perform to
>   reach its target.
>
> Write a function: `def solution(x, y, d)` that, given
>   three integers X, Y and D, returns the minimal number of jumps from
>   position X to a position equal to or greater than Y.
>
> For example,
>   given:
>   X = 10
>              Y = 85
>              D = 30
>
> the function should return 3,
>   because the frog will be positioned as follows:
>
> after the first jump,
>   at position 10 + 30 = 40
>
> after the second jump, at position 10 + 30 +
>   30 = 70
>
> after the third jump, at position 10 + 30 + 30 + 30 = 100
>   Assume that:
>
> X, Y and D are integers within the range
>   [1..1,000,000,000];
>
> X ≤ Y.
>
> Complexity: expected worst-case time
>   complexity is O(1);
>
> expected worst-case space complexity is O(1).

Here is my solution:

```
def solution(x, y, d)
    position = x
    positions = []
    until position >= y
        position += d
        positions << position
    end
    return positions.length

end
```

This solution works, but got a performance score of 0% and a correctness score of 100%.

My solution works on smaller data sets, but always times out on larger data sets.

Answer (score 4):

It's a math problem more than a programming problem.

The distance to cover is \$y - x\$, so we *divide* that with our "speed", `d`, and round up to get the number of jumps. No loops or anything, just arithmetic.

The only trick is that if `d` is an integer, our division will be imprecise, since \$\frac{85-10}{30} = 2.5\$ but the decimal gets dropped by everything being treated as integers.

So we can either make `d` a float using `to_f`, or we can use `fdiv` to force a more precise, floating point division.

Using the latter, you get:

```
def solution(x, y, d)
  (y - x).fdiv(d).ceil
end
```

The `return` can be skipped, since this is Ruby.

Using `to_f` you could do:

```
def solution(x, y, d)
  jumps = (y - x) / d.to_f
  jumps.ceil
end
```

Finally, as Caridorc points out, renaming the arguments could make this even clearer

```
def solution(start, goal, jump_distance)
  (goal - start).fdiv(jump_distance).ceil
end
```

---

The above is the more correct solution (again, it's a math problem), but if we pretend that we *do* need a loop, you don't need the array for anything. Instead you could just do:

```
def solution(x, y, d)
  jumps = 0
  until x >= y
    x += d
    jumps += 1
  end
  jumps
end
```

Again, not the right solution for the problem, but a better one than using an array.

Answer (score 2):

- Use longer names (you are not forced to use the one letter names they say)
- Repeated subtraction is division, you may express it with the symbol `/`

:

```
def solution(start_position, end_position, jump_distance)
    delta_space = end_position - start_position
    return (delta_space.to_f / jump_distance).ceil
end
```

Comment: This doesn't give the right result (giving the example input yields 2 jumps instead of 3 due to integer division). Also the `abs` is unnecessary since x ≤ y so you can just flip the operands. And you can skip the `return`

Answer (score 0):

Flambino's answer is great. I will add another way to solve this; although, as Flambino points out, it is a math problem and loops aren't needed. That said, you can use an Enumerator.

```
def jumps_needed(location:, destination:, jump_distance:)
  location.step(destination, jump_distance).size
end
```

The `step` method returns an Enumerator object, which responds to the `size` method. The enumerator's size is the number of jumps (or loop iterations) that the frog needs to reach its destination.

`step` can take up to two arguments; the first is the goal, or the value needed for the enumerator to terminate, and the second is the value by which to increment the goal.